# subset data.table by indexed column and rows

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking to subset a data table recursively, by changing the index of the column `z` AND at the same time filter rows based on some `%in%` based vector.

```
dt <- setDT(copy(diamonds))
dt <- setDT(data.frame(lapply(dt, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
z=4
subset_by <- unique(dt[,z])[1:2]
### obviously does not work
###dt1<-dt[ z %in% subset_by]
```

I am looking for the most memory-efficient operation to do this and I am sure there is a way without using colnames, but I just cannot find it. I looked at a lot of posts, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112658/data-table-in-r-subset-using-column-index) beign the most relevant

Comment: Your dataset is not longer `data.table` after converting to data.frame in the 2nd line.  You need `dt[z %in% subset_by,]`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. That's what i get when i try to create a reproducible example!

Comment: After converting to data.table, the way to subset columns should be either `unique(dt[[z]])[1:2]`

Comment: Thank you, I am not looking to simply select the first 2 (or any number of) rows . I want to subset based on some values using the `%in` operator

Comment: After that you can use `i1 <- dt[, .I[.SD[[1]] %in% subset_by],.SDcols = z]
; dt[i1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are subsetting based on the index or names, we can specify it in `.SDcols`

```
i1 <- dt[, .I[.SD[[1]] %chin% subset_by], .SDcols = z]
dt[i1]
```

Note that subsetting a column in `data.table/tbl_df/data_frame` would be either `[[` or `$`

```
subset_by <- unique(dt[[z]])[1:2]
```